# Get index from 2d array where first element is the index

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2D array that prints out the following:

```
[[0, {'dt_name': 'Go'}], [1, {'dt_name': 'Stop'}]]
```

I want to iterate through this list, so that I can retrieve the index value (first element) if `dt_name` is `Go` for example. I.e. return should be `0`. If `dt_name` is `Stop`, then return is `1`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

```
lst = [[0, {'dt_name': 'Go'}], [1, {'dt_name': 'Stop'}]]
res = next(i for (i, t) in lst if t['dt_name'] == 'Go')
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0
```

This approach avoids building any additional list.

Some timings on list vs generator:

```
lst = [[0, {'dt_name': 'Go'}], [1, {'dt_name': 'Stop'}]] * 100
%timeit next(i for (i, t) in lst if t['dt_name'] == 'Go')
452 ns ± 2.18 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit [i for (i, t) in lst if t['dt_name'] == 'Go'][0]
12.1 µs ± 36.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

In the above example using next on the generator is about 24 times faster.

Comment: I guess `next(...)` and `[...]` are synonymous in this example?

Comment: @caasswa [] creates a whole new list, just to fetch the first element using next only fetch the first element of the generator

Comment: @caasswa Though if you also wanted to test whether there was exactly one, then you would want to construct the list. (You could assign using e.g. `res, = [....]` and this would raise an exception if there is not exactly one - note the comma here - it is unpacking into a one-element tuple.) Using `next`, it will stop on the first match, which will be faster. Use whichever is more appropriate to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate though the list and check for your condition and in case you got it, you can break out of it and get your index.

As an example:

```
a = [[0, {'dt_name': 'Go'}], [1, {'dt_name': 'Stop'}]]
ans_idx = -1
for item in a:
  if item[1]['dt_name']=='go':
    ans_idx = item[0]
    break
```

if `ans_idx=-1`, that means you don't have an index for the same.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: For your info, @caasswa: Instead of initialising to `-1` before the loop, an alternative would be to have an `else:` block after the `for:` loop (the `else` statement on the same indentation level as the `for` rather than the `if`), and this will execute if no match was found (i.e. if the loop completed without early exit via `break`). You might decide to raise an exception in the `else:` block for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
>>> a = [[0, {'dt_name': 'Go'}], [1, {'dt_name': 'Stop'}]]
>>> [index] = [x for [x, t] in a if t['dt_name'] == 'Go']
>>> index
0
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was missing the `[x, t]` as i hadn't seen any examples except `x for x in` etc

Comment: Mostly a stylistic point, but I'd suggest using tuples rather than lists for this kind of assignment, so instead of `[index] = ...`, I suggest `(index,) = ...` (or the same thing with shorter syntax, `index, = ...`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with function like below:

```
def fnd_idx(lst, wrd):
    for l in lst:
        if l[1]['dt_name'] == wrd:
            return l[0]
    return -1
```

Output:

```
>>> lst = [[0, {'dt_name': 'Go'}], [1, {'dt_name': 'Stop'}]]

>>> fnd_idx(lst, 'Go')
0

>>> fnd_idx(lst, 'Stop')
1

>>> fnd_idx(lst, 'Start')
-1
```

Comment: That's a cute way too :) thanks